# Error: "The server does not have one or more of the database objects required"

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with my project ASP.NET using Visual Studio 2010

On the server explorer window when I try to expand the database I get the following error:

> This server does not have one or more of the database objects required to use database diagramming. Do you wish to create them? Yes/No/Help

It was working this morning, I am not sure what is wrong, is this a bug or something?

How can I fix this error?

I have tried to re-install Visual Studio. It didn't help.

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to expand `Database Diagrams` where you mean to click `Tables`?

Comment: I am clicking database diagrams yes it was opening but not anymore, the tables are not the same with this.

Comment: Can you properly explain what you did, what you are trying to do and what is happening? Do you mean you created a database diagram earlier and are now unable to find or open it?

Comment: I have a university project written in ASP.NET, The teacher told us to modify the tables of employees. I was able to expand the Database Diagrams but now i am getting that error. The table view does not have that tables we are asked to modify. I have not done anything only updated my windows.